# Drupal 7 submit function not called for themed form

Tags: theming, forms

I am developing a form. 2 functions are:

```
function reserve_multi_step_form($form, &$form_state)
{
       $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'reserve');

       $form['#theme'] = 'reserve_form_2';
       $form["agreed"] = array(
                            '#type' => 'checkbox',
                            '#title' => t("I accept the deposit policy"),
                            '#attributes' => array("onChange" => "policy_accepted();"),
                            );


       $form['submit'] = array(
                       '#type' => 'submit',
                       '#value' => t('Submit'),
                       '#attributes' => array('style' => "padding: 0 10px;"),
                       "#disabled" => true,
                       );

       return $form;
    }

function reserve_multi_step_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
       print 1111;exit;
}
```

The theme function:

```
function reserve_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
   return array(
                'reserve_form_2' => array(
                                          'render element' => 'form',
                                          'template' => 'reserve_form_2',
                                          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'reserve'),
                                          ),
}
```

In the template file I print some text and render the form:

```
    <?php
    print "text";
    print drupal_render_children($variables["form"]);
```

The form is displayed correctly. But after I click submit button, the reserve_multi_step_form_submit is not called. Without theming it works. What can be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `#disabled` property set on your submit element. Drupal's form API does not process the input for any element, including submit buttons, if the `#disabled` property is set on the server side.

If you're interested in the code behind this, the decisions are made in the [`_form_builder_handle_input_element()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/7) function in the `includes/form.inc` file of your Drupal installation.

If you want the submit button to be disabled by default for client-side purposes (i.e. you'll be enabling it through JS based on some action taken by the user) you would be better off setting the `disabled` attribute directly on the element, as Drupal pays no attention to this when processing the form:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'style' => "padding: 0 10px;",
    'disabled' => 'disabled'
  )
);
```